# MySQL - Insert values if not exists or update and return id

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table which looks f.ex. like this:

id (primaryKey, auto_increment) | fruit | color

I would like to insert values for *fruit* and *color*, if the *fruit* value does not exist, else I would like to update just the *color* and get back the *id* of the inserted or updated row.

F.ex. if I have a row with:

1234 | apple | red

and want to update the *color* of the apple to green, without knowing that there is already a row containing an apple. I use this code:

```
$sqli = get_db();
$q1 = "INSERT INTO table (fruit, color) VALUES ('apple', 'green') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE color='green', id=LAST_INSERT_ID(id)";
$r1 = $sqli->query($q1);
$insertedOrUpdatedID = $sqli->insert_id();
```

I want to update the existing row to:

1234 | apple | green

and get back the *id* (1234) in $insertedOrUpdatedID.

I think I need to tag the *fruit* column in any way. When I'm executing this code, it always creates a new row (123**5**|apple|green) without updating the existing one or returning the edited *id*.

**SOLUTION:**

Changing the type of 'fruit' from *text* to *varchar(100)* and setting its KEY to UNIQUE solves the problem. Moreover change the last line of the code to:

```
$insertedOrUpdatedID = mysqli_insert_id( $sqli );
```

in order to get the right ID.

Happy coding!

Comment: Have you looked a REPLACE instead of INSERT [see the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replace.html)

Comment: `UNIQUE` constraint to `fruit` attribute may prevent inserting duplicate rows.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Thanks, but unfortunately when I am executing REPLACE INTO table (fruit, color) VALUES ('apple', 'green') it still creates a second row

Comment: @soonoo Thanks, but when I am trying to change _fruit_ to UNIQUE, MySQL says "BLOB/TEXT column 'fruit' used in key specifications without a key length", also when I set the length to 100

Comment: @soonoo **EDIT: - changing it to varchar(100) and then to UNIQUE did the trick and it WORKS! Thank you!! **

Comment: @user3191334 :- If storage engine is Myisam then it works but if innoDB then for every insert or update action it increments primary autoincrement value each time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to update by fruit name so create fruite as **UNIQUE KEY**

Try this query

`REPLACE INTO table_name (fruit,color) VALUES ('apple','green');`

**OR**

`INSERT INTO table_name (fruit,color) VALUES ('apple','green') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE color = 'green;`

Comment: THANKS! And also thanks to @soonoo!! The trick was to change the 'fruit' type from text to varchar(100) and then make it UNIQUE ! Now the insert query works!

Comment: Welcome friend... It's my pleasure :)